# How to clone a deck in Anki?

Tags: anki

How can I clone a deck of flashcards in [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net)?

I want to make a new deck which contains all the same cards as a deck I already have, with all the same fields and information, but I want to add at least one new field to the new cards, manually edit it for each card, and also delete some cards and add some new cards to the new deck only.

Comment: Anki just uses a database file last I knew, so you could just copy the file. The steps to do that would be different depending on the platform you are using: iPhone/iOS, Google/Android, Anki on the web, etc.

Comment: @gregg well, I would like to keep both decks in one instance of Anki.

Comment: If you are using this on a smartphone/tablet please advice Android or iOS. Otherwise I'd assume you are using the website. I am confident you could do it manually, but I haven't used it in years. This appears to be an add-on that can do it for you: https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1779572689
https://docs.ankiweb.net/files.html

Comment: @gregg I'm using the desktop app. Thanks for that add-on link, I'll see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this version](https://github.com/ijgnd/anki-copy-note) of the Copy notes add-on because the authoritative one has errors that stop it working.

To install it, I had to

```
git clone https://github.com/ijgnd/anki-copy-note.git ~/Library/Application\ Support/Anki2/addons21/ijgnd-copy-note
```

Then restart Anki.

To make a new deck that contains all the same notes as a deck you already have:

1. Open Anki's Browse window.
2. Click on your deck in the left sidebar.
3. Click on the first note (to focus the note list)
4. Press cmd-A (ctrl-a) to select all the notes.
5. Right-click them then click Notes (or use the Notes menu bar item) and click Note Copy
6. Now add tag:Copy to the search bar at the top of the list, to show only notes in this deck that are also copies
7. Use cmd-A to select them all
8. Right-click and choose "Change deck", then change to the new deck you've made
9. Click on the new deck in the left sidebar
10. Use cmd-A to select all the notes in the new deck
11. Right-click, choose Notes, then Change Note Type and select the new note type you've made for them (if you want them to have a new note type — I did because I wanted the notes in the new deck to have additional fields and information that the original deck shouldn't have)
12. And if you care, you can remove the Copy tag from them by selecting them all, right-clicking, then Notes then Remove Tags... then just type `Copy` and press Ok.
13. If you want to "reset" the deck's progress (next new cards, revisions etc.) to make it as if this is a brand new deck, then select all the notes in the new deck and right-click and choose `Forget`